# How do I strengthen my false grip to do a muscle-up?

Tags: muscle-ups

I have been learning to do muscle up for past few week and still could not do one. 
For the past few weeks I have been using my legs to try and kick myself up, but still could not do a muscle up.

I have found that my false grip is weak and could not do a proper pull-up using false grip.

Should I continue to train using my leg or should I train on my false grip first?

How do I strengthen my false grip? Will hanging on the pull up bar using false grip help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After month of training in gym and week of sweat at the pull up bar i manage to do my first muscle up.
before i do my muscle up i went to the gym to warm up my shoulder and do some false grip pull up using the pull up bar there with some support from machine for around 30min.

Once i finish my warm up i went to the pull up bar and try stretching and hanging there using false grip for a min. Before i try pulling myself up to do a muscle up. first attempt i failed. Remembering what a cross fit instructor told me that my elbow is too wide. So i tried again forcing my elbow close to me and i went smoothly i done a muscle up without difficulty.

So i feel muscle up is more about the tactic of doing it rather then how strong we are how many pull up we can do. The tactic of kicking and the false grip is the key to doing a muscle up for beginner so is better to do both at a time. I dont a muscle up although my false grip is still weak.

still need help in some tip for strengthening my false grip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to focus on doing some grip training.  Start by taking 2 - 10 or 25 pound plates and grip then between your fingers for time.  Or try to find thicker grip bars to use for training.  Also to improve something you generally prioritize it.  That means if you want to improve your false grip in pullups, start every workout doing a few dozen reps.  Over the course of a few weeks the body's adaptations process will become accustomed to that type of movement, thus strengthening your initial goal.

Answer (score -2):

hang some small kettle bells up side down from the rings. Do false grip pull ups with them. You welcome. -Ali G

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the kettle bells hung upside down? Because I don't quite understand.